# Third-party frameworks embedded into .xcframework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

I would like to use RxSwift inside my .xcframwork, is there any 'good practice' to add third-party frameworks to your .xcframework to be able to ship it 'all in one' for the customer?

I was trying to generate RxSwift.framework from their github repo, and add it to the framework itself, but didn't work at the end, while using with Example app have this error:
[image]

Any link or idea would be welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I decided to add RxSwift as a package to my Framework and then expose RxSwift agnostic interface of the Framework for the customer, so they will be not aware that Im using under the hood Rx. I had to mark all RxSwift imports as `@_implementationOnly import RxSwift`.

Another benefit of this is that customer of my Framework is not forced to have a knowledge about RxSwift since Im using vanilla Swift (closures).

Comment: Hi may I know what dependency manager you used to import RxSwift?

Comment: Hi sure, in this particular case, I was using SPM.